# EBCDIC - ASCII converstion with Websphere MQ and WAS 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-7

I'm working with Websphere 7 and Websphere MQ 7 I have a
message driven bean (MDB) deployed in Websphere which is bound to a (WebSphere MQ Activation Specification) configured queue. 
The MDB will be receiving messages in EDCIDIC format and need to convert this  into ASCII.
In the past, directly connecting to the MQ server using native MQ API we had the option to programmatically 
convert the message using i.e.  the following excerpt:

```
gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT; //Handles EBCDIC/ASCII
getq = qmgr.accessQueue(responseQueue);
while(true)
{
    MQMessage msgId = new MQMessage();
    msgId.characterSet = 1208;
    getq.get(msgId, gmo);
}
```

But using MDB’s (JMS)  there doesn't seem to be an option to instruct the conversion.
I suspect Websphere should have a setting to do the conversion as it acts as a bridge between 
MQ server and the MDB but can’t seem to find a setting in the console.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005729&aid=1 , https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc%2Ffr20890_.htm

Comment: This might help you also http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21459994

Comment: Thanks Guys,  I'm currently testing a variety of configuration options at my disposal. One being on the MQ Server Channel or on Websphere.  Great post and thanks again